# Using regex 'or' and capturing groups at the same time

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the 'ephname' expressions below (depends on the file which one is present), but I only want the numbers to be captured:

```
entries = ['other data\nephdelay = 12\nephname = cfghjk78.comb\nother data', 'other data\nephdelay = 17\nephname = qwerty.s92\nother data']
```

I'm using this is as my regex, but no matches are showing up (however it works just for one if I pick one and remove the boolean):

```
\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+)\s?|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?
```

I've tested this on regex websites and I don't see what the problem is. I want the output to be either '94' or '78' depending on the entry. Why aren't I getting any matches?

Edit:
In my code I have this:

```
import re
commonterms = (["term1", "#term1pattern"],
               ["ephsol", "\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+)\s?|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?"],
               ["term3", "#term3pattern"], ...)

terms = [commonterms[i][0] for i in range(len(commonterms))]
patterns = [commonterms[i][1] for i in range(len(commonterms))]

d = {t: [] for t in terms}

def getTerms(entry):
    for i in range(len(terms)):
        term = re.search(patterns[i], entry)
        term = term.groups()[0] if term else 'NULL'
    return d

for entry in entries:
    d = getTerms(entry)

print d['ephsol']
```

Then when I print `d['ephsol']` I just get a bunch of NULLs, but I know there should be matches.

Comment: The groups are correctly matched for me https://regex101.com/r/HaN4N3/1 How are you getting the groups in your code?

Comment: You use complicated regex in an easy case, you should just use \d and it will match each number individually or you can use \d{2} if you want sure that it will be 2 numbers and in this case it will return one match of the two numbers.

Comment: @FadySaad I've simplified my situation for the sake of this question, but in reality these things I'm trying to match are in a document of many other letters and numbers so I do need to make sure the 'ephgen' is there

Comment: I'm getting a `yes`. I replaced `entries[i]` with both of your test cases. You may want to print `entries[i]` in the loop

Comment: @tima I've edited my question so now `entries` is closer to what I'm actually dealing with and the loop makes more sense

Comment: it works https://repl.it/KmCX/0

Comment: Thanks, the only thing different now is just that my actual `entries` is very long and complicated but it should still work. I have no idea why it's not working on my script.

Comment: Cool, but just so you know I didn't make any changes in the link I provided. All the code is copied from this question.

Comment: @WynneT You'll need to post some actual data that fails. And be more careful when copying the code, your posted code had a line break in the regexp string.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the current issue I am facing with not getting any matches. (the code yesterday was a different issue which is fixed now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is based on the edited question.*

The assignment in the `getTerms` function is not correct. You are assigning only the first, `0`, group but the match can be in the second group. Also, you are returning `d` which you do not change.

Here is how it can be done:

```
# anything above this line was not changed

d = {}

# d is: term - list of matches
for i in range(len(terms)):
  d[terms[i]] = []

# for each entry
for entry in entries:

  # for each term
  for i in range(len(terms)):

    # get match
    m = re.search(patterns[i], entry)

    # matched
    if m:

      # check for group 1
      if m.group(1):
        # add match to the term list
        d[terms[i]].append(m.group(1))

      # check for group 2
      elif m.group(2):
        # add match to the term list
        d[terms[i]].append(m.group(2))

    # did not match
    else:
      # add null to the term list
      d[terms[i]].append('NULL')

print d
print
print d['ephsol']
```

Output

```
{'ephsol': ['78', '92'], 'term3': ['NULL', 'NULL'], 'term1': ['NULL', 'NULL']}

['78', '92']
```

https://repl.it/Ko2L/0

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is that you have a match in one of two different groups:

```
entries = ['other data\nephdelay = 12\nephname = cfghjk78.comb\nother data', 'other data\nephdelay = 17\nephname = qwerty.s92\nother data']

for e in entries:
    m=re.search(r'\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+)\s?|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?', e)
    if m:
        print "Group 1: {}, Group 2: {} {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.groups())
```

Prints:

```
Group 1: None, Group 2: 78 (None, '78')
Group 1: 92, Group 2: None ('92', None)
```

To print either one, you might do:

```
for e in entries:
    m=re.search(r'\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?\.s(\d+)\s?|\s?ephname\s?=\s?.*?(\d+)\.comb\s?', e)
    if m:
        print m.group(1) if m.group(1) is not None else m.group(2)
```

Prints:

```
78
92
```

The other alternative is to [change your regex](https://regex101.com/r/YdF5LH/1/) so that the capture is always in group 1:

```
for e in entries:
    m=re.search(r'^ephname[ \t]*=[ \t]*[^0-9\n]*(\d+)(?:\.comb|\s)', e, flags=re.M)
    if m:
        print m.group(1)
```

Prints:

```
78
92
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to eliminate some of your '?' characters because they are messing up the match.  '?' Must have at least one match.  Also, it helps to use re.DOTALL so that the '.' character includes new lines ('\n').

Here is what I came up with:

```
import re

entries = ['other data\nephdelay = 12\nephname = cfghjk78.comb\nother data', 'other data\nephdelay = 17\nephname = qwerty.s92\nother data']

pattern = '.*ephname\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z\.]*(\d+)\s*|.*ephname\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z\.]*(\d+)\.comb\s*'

pObj = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)

match = pObj.match(entries[0])

match2 = pObj.match(entries[1])

print(match.group(1))
print("**********divider")
print(match2.group(1))


print("\n\nReprinting the input date\n\n")
print(entries[0])
print(entries[1])
```